# How to print on screen all the parameters of a function

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation

I am trying to pass a function to `createTextNode` so that I will have printed on screen : `i am singing Let It GO` & `i am dancing as well while singing` which are passed to the function through parameters.

The problem is that only the first argument appears.

```
function sing(song ,dance){
   return`i am singing ${song}`
   callback();
 }

function dance(){
   return "i am dancing as well while singing";
}

let singing=sing("Let It GO","dance");
const elP=document.createElement("p");
const elT=document.createTextNode(singing)
elP.appendChild(elT);    
document.body.appendChild(elP);
```

Comment: Please can you properly format your question.  It is hard to understand without proper formatting.

Comment: You can use string interpolation with the `dance` parameter too just as you did with `song`. I have posted an answer with both the extra function approach that you orignally did as well as with a direct parameter input in the `sing()` function. Check out both code snippets in the answer to see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reference `dance` using **[string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** the same way you referenced `song` like this:

```js
function sing(song ,dance){
   return `i am singing ${song}, ${dance}`;
}
function dance(){
   return "i am dancing as well while singing";
}

let singing=sing("Let It GO", dance());
const elP=document.createElement("p");
const elT=document.createTextNode(singing)
elP.appendChild(elT);    
document.body.appendChild(elP);
```

---

However, if the dance function only returns a string, a cleaner approach would be to reference the `dance` string in the `sing()` parameter itself as you did with the `song` string.

In the following I created a function called `sing` just as you did and simply used `${song}` and `${dance}` to retrieve the parameters, input the parameter values within the function parentheses itself and use them anywhere I want may it be in a *console log* or a *div* or an *alert box*.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/3x2asrLd/12/) or run the **Code Snippet** below to see the results of the following code:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("output");

function sing(song, dance) {
  div.innerHTML =  `<p>The song is: <strong>${song}</strong> and the dance is: <strong>${dance}</strong></p>`
}

sing("HipHop", "BreakDance");
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help Kaz. Do mark this or any of the other answers as the correct one if it helped you in solving your issue (Just click the tick mark on the left of the answer). Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2):

While the approach is a bit odd to me, what you have to do is to pass the function as an argument to the `sing` function and then callback that argument:

```js
function sing(song, callback){
   return`i am singing ${song} ${callback()}`
 }

function dance(){
   return "i am dancing as well while singing";
}

let singing=sing("Let It GO", dance);
const elP=document.createElement("p");
const elT=document.createTextNode(singing)
elP.appendChild(elT);    
document.body.appendChild(elP);
```

Comment: thanks a lot I think yours is the best solution ! :  )

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no concept of printing to screen, a crude way of debugging, but has console methods which serves the same purpose.

Javascript has special keywords called `arguments` which holds all the values passed to a function. So following code should print all the arguments passed to your function:

```
function hello(a, b, c) {
  console.log(arguments);
}

hello("World", 42, true);
```

Comment: Does this print to screen?

Comment: This prints to console. From the title of your question, I thought you are looking a way to see all arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need use dance as an argument at sing()

```js
function dance(){
   return "i am dancing as well while singing.";
}

function sing(song){
   var c = dance();
   return "i am singing " + song + "<br>" + c;
}


document.write(sing("foo"))
```